# Blogger image post viewer can't show

Tags: html, image, blogger

Blogger image post viewer can't show popup view when I use image crop in the post, it's will show new url page image.
But when I use image without crop, viewer can show popup view.

[image: Difference on use -c & not]

[image: Image with three divs]

Comment: edit your question and post the code in here, the picture is ok, but